# How to re-use token using snowflake node connector?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been asked to report an issue with connecting to Snowflake using the node connector here.

Issue: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/issues/113

The issue is I can't find any documentation on how to re-use an existing token to avoid taking a long time when connecting to Snowflake.

Would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I use:

```
// Tokens are retrieved from a DB
if (tokens) {
  connection.masterToken = tokens.masterToken;
  connection.masterTokenExpirationTime = tokens.masterTokenExpirationTime;
  connection.sessionToken = tokens.sessionToken;
  connection.sessionTokenExpirationTime = tokens.sessionTokenExpirationTime;
}
connection.connect(async function (err, conn) {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    resolve();
  }
});
```

Comment: I've had similar issues. For us the process is to get a JWT token via a web service. I haven't tested this, but suspect this could be re-used.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a full answer, but hopefully it helps you or someone else.  I've had similar issues. For us the process is to get a JWT token via a web service. I haven't tested this, but suspect this could be re-used.The JSON response includes a "lease_duration" property. I'm guessing this is in seconds, but do not know though I tried to check. To give you an idea, one value I got for this is 2764800. You could calculate the do something like:

```
Long leaseDurationInMs = Long.parseLong(result.get("lease_duration"));
Date estimatedLeaseExpiration = new Date(leaseStartTime+leaseDurationInMs);
System.out.println("Estimated lease expiration timestamp (human readable): "+estimatedLeaseExpiration);
Long estimatedLeaseExpirationInMs = estimatedLeaseExpiration.getTime();
```

and if then check this value each time you would have fetched whatever this token thing is to see if you need to get another one.

Comment: The problem is that it seems to ignore whatever token I pass on and tries to re-login every time, even after a few seconds. 

I have added the code I use to login (shortened) in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question but I ended up caching the data on my side to avoid connecting too often.